# Pyopengl on pydroid3

Tags: python, pyopengl, pydroid

Trying to get pyopengl working with Pydroid 3 on my android and can't quite get it to work. It throws me an error when I try to import it:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 3, in

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/**init**.py", line 4, in

```
from OpenGL.GL.VERSION.GL_1_1 import *
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/VERSION/GL_1_1.py", line 14, in

```
from OpenGL.raw.GL.VERSION.GL_1_1 import *
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GL/VERSION/GL_1_1.py", line 7, in

```
from OpenGL.raw.GL import _errors
```

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GL/_errors.py", line 4, in

```
_error_checker = _ErrorChecker( _p, _p.GL.glGetError )
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'glGetError'

I kinda have no idea what to do

I've Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pydroid 3, pygame, and PyOpenGL.